# Distinguishing which type of user clicked an ad

Tags: android, mobile, analytics, ads

I have a mobile (Android) app wherein I'll be serving ads to generate revenue (by users clicking on the ads). I'll have two types of users (type A and type B let's say). Type A is such that I get to keep all ad click-through revenue. Type B is such that I need to split ad click-through revenue between myself and a third-party.

I can distinguish between the two types of users in my app no problem. The problem is, I need to determine which proportion of my revenues has been generated by users of type B (to pay the third-party accordingly). Anyone have any ideas on whether this can be achieved and how, or even if there is an ad providing service that offers this functionality? I am inclined towards using AdMob ads but am open to other ad providers...

> **Edit:** Sorry to complicate and not be clear from the outset but there is a large possibility that type B will be split further so I will have to split revenue with third-party B1 for users who have downloaded my app via B1, and I will have to split revenue with third-party B2 for users who have downloaded my app via B2, and so on for an unknown number of third-parties.

Comment: It is enough to tag the question with 'Android', better not to put it in the title

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to load ads from different providers for the different types of users. Then you just split the revenue from one of the providers.

Comment: Sorry David, there is a slight complication that I've added to my question. Please have a look. If there's no ad provider that offers the functionality to differentiate the type of a user clicking an ad, I guess I'll have to go with your suggestion or something similar...

Comment: So it is not the users that are different, but the markets they downloaded the application from? This is relevant because in one case the application has to know the user, in the other it has to know the market it came from

Comment: I'm assuming for now we can differentiate users according to the market they installed the app from (even if this means releasing different apks to the different markets, but hopefully we'll find a better solution).

Answer (score 1):

How are you serving the ads? Are they third party code snippets that hit third party servers which do the tracking? Or do you go through your own server first and forward the requests to their destination?

The normal way to do this is to identify the user via a URL param in the ad's click-through URL. If you route the requests through your own servers, you can extract this information and identify the clicks as being a specific user, a specific user type, etc. and then forward the request on. If the URLs go directly to a third party, will they allow you to tag on extra parameters and will this show up in your reporting?

Without knowing exactly how you have it setup, it's hard to give you any definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason. Ideally I'd like to serve the ads by means of third party code snippets that hit third party servers, and such that allow me to differentiate and keep count of click-throughs by each of the different types of users. So looking for an ad provider that can provide this functionality if you or anyone else knows of one? Worst case going to have to find a work-around like David described or your suggestion to add server code myself to keep count of clicks by the different types of users.